# What's the best IDE for DigitalMars D programming?

Tags: ide, d

Digital Mars D seems to be very good programming language in a lot of ways, but my only problem with it is the amount of time wasted writing arguments to the compiler in the command line at the old fashion way. Is there any good IDE for D? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [An IDE for D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179/an-ide-for-d)

Comment: Information about IDEs suitable for D programming can be found here: https://wiki.dlang.org/IDEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being looking around and testing all the IDEs recommended in this question and the one in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179/an-ide-for-d, I was not comfortable with any of the answers. I was begining to believe that really there is not such thing as a "best IDE" for D, but recently I found one that is in my point of view a very good solution: **[SkyIDE](http://www.techopinion.net/start/node/6)**

[image]
<sub>(source: [hubpages.com](http://z.hubpages.com/u/77709_f520.jpg))</sub>

It is also a Good IDE for Digital Mars C++, Free Pascal and other languages...

Comment: Does it have debugger support?  The lousy debug options are my main gripe with D right now.

Comment: Does SkyIDE still exist? Both the link above and http://www.skyide.net/ are dead links at the moment. You can still find an EXE on CNet but it looks like the project may have disappeared.

Answer (score 13):

The best IDE to use for D is probably the IDE you use most often and are most comfortable with.

If you like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) you should check-out [DDT (D Development Tools)](https://ddt-ide.github.io/) (formerly Descent)

If you like Visual Studio you should check-out [VisualD](http://www.dsource.org/projects/visuald).

There is also [D for XCode](http://michelf.com/projects/d-for-xcode/) but it seems to have fallen behind.

Another interesting option is [Mono-D](http://mono-d.sourceforge.net/) which adds nice D support to [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/). It works on Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Mono-D supports code completion, syntax highlighting, class browsing, error highlighting, 'Go to definition', intelligent code formatting, and more. If you like MonoDevelop, or need cross-platform support, it seems like a good choice.

MonoDevelop (and Mono-D) use the Visual Studio project format. It is possible that VisualD and Mono-D are able to share project files. I have not tested this.

**EDIT:** I just ran across [this link](http://prowiki.com/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?EditorSupport) that does a nice job of showing D IDE options including how actively they are developed.

Comment: +1 for Mono-D (For a Linux Mint/Ubuntu user). Seems to make a decent job even on debugging, out of the box.

Comment: http://ddt-ide.github.io/

Answer (score 7):

Please try my [D-IDE](http://d-ide.sourceforge.net/) and check out if this IDE is the best one you'll find ;)

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried D in them, so you'll need to do your own eval, but:

- [Slickedit 2009](http://www.slickedit.com/content/view/498/#DLanguageSupport), and
- [Zeus Editor](http://zeusedit.com/d.html)

both claim full support for D.

Answer (score -1):

[geany](http://www.geany.org/) is best ide for D programming:

Support D programming

Syntax hightlighting

Autocompletion

is easy to set D compiler ldc, gdc or dmd or use instead a make file

if you do not have makefile for your little porject you can use this command(example)

ldc -of "../%e" $(find . -name "*.d")